# To merge value of Selected Radio button and Checbox in a Text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button

My jQuery code is mentioned below.

```
$('.meraCheck').click(function () {
    var text1 = "";
    $('.meraCheck:checked').each(function () {
        text1 += $(this).parent().text() + ',';
    });
    text1 = text1.substring(0, text1.length - 1);

    $('#selectedConsiderationsText').val(text1);

    var pane = $('#selectedConsiderationsText');
    var trimmed_text= pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n').replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));
});

$('.meraRadio').click(function () {
    var text = "";
    $('.meraRadio:checked').each(function () {
        text += $(this).parent().text() + ',';
    });
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);

    $('#selectedConsiderationsText').val(text);

    var pane = $('#selectedConsiderationsText');
    pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n').replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));
});
```

Currently in Text area it reflects text as mentioned below:

- If I select Checkbox  ( as class 'meraCheck'will get clicked ) then in textara it
  reflects value of selected checkbox only.
- If I select Checkbox  ( as class 'meraRadio'will get clicked ) then in textara it reflects value of selected radiobuttons only.

What I want is that I want to merge value both of selected checbox and radio buttons both  (at the sametime)
in that textarea.

Can please anyone assist me how it will be done?

Code for Checbkox,Radiobutton and Text area is here:

```
 <input isselected="True" checked="checked" class="meraCheck"  type="checkbox" value="12389" style="transform: scale(1);">
     <input class="meraRadio"  style="transform: scale(1);margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" value="11100">

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="selectedConsiderationsText"></textarea>
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle for easy understanding

Comment: Please add the code for checkbox, radio and textarea!

Comment: @Pugazh Can you please check now. I have added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check below answer!

```js
$(function() {

  $('.meraCheck, .meraRadio').click(function() {
    var text1 = "";
    $('.meraCheck:checked').each(function() {
      text1 += $(this).val() + ',';
    });

    $('.meraRadio:checked').each(function() {
      text1 += $(this).val() + ',';
    });

    text1 = text1.substring(0, text1.length - 1);

    $('#selectedConsiderationsText').val(text1);

    var pane = $('#selectedConsiderationsText');
    var trimmed_text = pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n').replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input isselected="True" name="meraCheck" class="meraCheck" type="checkbox" value="12389" style="transform: scale(1);">12389
<input isselected="True" name="meraCheck" class="meraCheck" type="checkbox" value="12390" style="transform: scale(1);">12390

<input class="meraRadio" name="meraRadio" style="transform: scale(1);margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" value="11100">11100
<input class="meraRadio" name="meraRadio" style="transform: scale(1);margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" value="11101">11101

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="selectedConsiderationsText"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.meraCheck').click(function() {
    updateText();
  });

  $('.meraRadio').click(function() {
    updateText();
  });

  function updateText() {
    var text = "";
    $('.meraRadio:checked').each(function() {
      text += $(this).parent().text() + ',';
    });

    $('.meraCheck:checked').each(function() {
      text += $(this).parent().text() + ',';
    });
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);

    $('#selectedConsiderationsText').val(text);

    var pane = $('#selectedConsiderationsText');
    var trimmed_text = pane.val($.trim(pane.val()).replace(/\s*[\r\n]+\s*/g, '\n').replace(/(<[^\/][^>]*>)\s*/g, '$1').replace(/\s*(<\/[^>]+>)/g, '$1'));


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>My CheckBox
  <input isselected="True" class="meraCheck" type="checkbox" value="12389" style="transform: scale(1);">
</div>
<div>My RadioBox
  <input class="meraRadio" style="transform: scale(1);margin-left: 25px;" type="radio" value="11100">
</div>
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="selectedConsiderationsText"></textarea>
```